Using Kotlin HOFs to split, transform, and join elements from String list
Goal:
Given a list of String representing IP addresses

split into 4 octets by removing '.'
transform split pieces by padding with zeros (if size == 1 or 2)
join pieces into a 12-char String, returning a new list

Example
        input:      8.219.27.102
        output:     008219027102
    

I've got code to do this imperatively, but am attempting to solve it using just
Kotlin higher-order list functions.
 val ipList = arrayListOf<String>(
        "8.219.27.102","13.111.16.143","104.168.41.0","104.168.41.84","104.206.192.0","104.223.153.0",
        "168.203.37.240","192.3.195.0","198.255.103.0"
    )

// fun to transfrom octets 
//
fun padStringWithZeros(s: String) : String {
    return when (s.length) {
        1 -> "00$s"
        2 -> "0$s"
        else -> {
            s
        }
    }
}

Using map to split on '.' I get the 4 octets separated by ', '
val ipListXFormed =    ipList
  .map { it.split(".").toString() }
        
[8, 219, 27, 102]
[13, 111, 16, 143]
...

Adding a flatmap split on "," gets me the individual pieces
  val ipListXFormed =    ipList
        .map { it.split(".").toString() }.flatMap { it.split(",") }

[8
 219
 27
 102]
[13
 111
 16
 143]
...
 

But, if I try to use map to transform these pieces, it seems to be including the brackets
as chars in the elements, which throws off the element size.
I'm a bit stuck here...can this be done simply with HOFs or would imperative style be more appropriate?

What's the purpose for which you want to do this? If it's just for Kotlin programming practice, then see Sweeper's answer. If you actually want to translate an IPv4 address to a single-part format, then you're doing it wrong. The single number is treated as a 32-bit integer. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Inet4Address.html#format

Purpose was to sort the IPs. I believe sorting the String list accomplishes this.

split already gives you a List<String>. But for some reason you call toString on it and tries to parse the string you got back into a List.
Don't do that - just use what you get from split directly. Join the split octets again with joinToString, and use padStart to add the zeroes.
ipList.map { ip ->
    ip.split('.')
        .joinToString(separator = "") {
            it.padStart(3, '0')
        }
}


Thanks, this makes it clear where and how to use .joinToString()

FOLLOWUP
Wanted to post my solution to the reverse of the original question: reconstructing IP addresses from the String list by adding back the '.' separators.
val reconstructedIPs = ipList
    .map {
        it.chunked(3)
            .joinToString(separator = ".") {
                it.removePrefix("0").removePrefix("0")
            }
}

I used .removePrefix("0") twice above as using this replace call with a regex didn't work:
it.replace("(^0)|(^00)", "")

Probably a simpler way to do this, but it works.

This works: it.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)".toRegex(), "")

This was an X-Y Problem: you wanted to know how to sort a list of IP addresses, but instead you asked how to turn an IP address into a custom string format.
To sort a list of IP addresses is very easy:
val sortedList = ipList.sortedBy {
    it.split(".").map { it.toUInt() }.reduce { acc, i -> acc * 256u + i}
}

This sorts the IP addresses by turning them into an equivalent unsigned int.
You don't have to turn the IP addresses back to the original format, because the sorted list is already in the original format.

Nice, thanks. I wanted help with X so I could solve Y myself; which I did. Yours is the better solution.
